# Angular 4 Data Table params

Tags: javascript, angular, datatables

I am trying to have my data table reflect the first demo [here](https://ggmod.github.io/angular-2-data-table-demo/). Due to lack of good documentation, I am not able to implement the 3 fields at the bottom properly. Mainly I want the limit option and to display the pages on the left in that form instead of the buttons that are defaulted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table-demo/tree/master/app
please find this link will answer your question

Comment: @awh112 I'm not looking for someone to write code for me, just an example of how parameters are set for the table. The demo that vikash referenced isn't very clear either on how the parameters are set. I've already put several hours in looking for this information.